# Accessing object properties within an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, methods

I'm working with paper.js and I want to create a method that dynamically alters the color property of each "Ball" object instance once every second. Imagine I have an object:

```
var Ball = function(point, vector) {

    this.point = point;
    this.dampen = .6;
    this.gravity = 0;
    this.bounce = -.6;


    var radius = this.radius = 10 * Math.random() + 30;

    var ball = new Path.Circle({
        radius: radius,

        fillColor: palette[Math.floor(Math.random()*palette.length)]
    });

    this.item = new Group({
        children: [ball],
        transformContent: false,
        position: this.point
    });
}
```

I want to add a new object method to "Ball" via "prototype" like so

```
Ball.prototype = {
    recolor: function() {
        // do stuff here
    }
}
```

Obviously I need to be able to access the "fillColor" property of the variable "ball", but I'm struggling to find a way to do so, I thought from within the recolor method I would be able to use the following:

```
this.item.children[i].fillColor
```

or

```
this.item.children[i].Path.fillColor
```

However both return "undefined" so obviously I'm being stupid! What would be the correct way to setup a prototyped method to change the color of the Ball object every second?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your example with little changes and it works for me. Just guessing your objects.

Think its something related to how you have defined Group object. I tried :

```
function Group(obj) {
        this.children = [];
        this.transformContent=false;
        this.position=0.0;
       $.extend(this, obj);
   }
```

Also you can try `this.item.children.push(ball);` after you initialise this.item.

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3hzgjp80/)

```js
(function Init(){  
    function Circle(obj) {
        this.radius = 0;
        this.fillColor=0;
       $.extend(this, obj);
   }
    
     function Group(obj) {
        this.children = [];
        this.transformContent=false;
        this.position=0.0;
       $.extend(this, obj);
   }
    
    var Ball = function(point, vector) {
    this.point = point;
    this.dampen = .6;
    this.gravity = 0;
    this.bounce = -.6;
    var radius = this.radius = 10 * Math.random() + 30;

    var ball = new Circle({
        radius: radius,
        fillColor: 10
    });

    this.item = new Group({
        children: [ball],
        transformContent: false,
        position: point
    });
}
    
    Ball.prototype = {
    recolor: function() {
        // do stuff here
        var f = this.item.children[0].fillColor; 
        console.log("f:"+f)
    }
}

    var b = new Ball(6,7);
    b.recolor();
    
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```